# Faster way to process xml in mule

Tags: mule

We are having an xml request that is very huge which contains nearly 10000 xml elements as shown below

```
<root>
   <message></message>
   <message></message>
   <message></message>
         .....
         .....
         .....
         .....
   <message></message>
   <message></message>
   <message></message>
</root>
```

In mule we are using xpath extractor in for-each processor, which is taking huge amount of time.
Is there a way where we can process huge xml files faster in mule ?

```
    <foreach doc:name="Foreach" batchSize="1" collection="#[xpath://message]">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </foreach>
```

Also changing batchSize didn't help.
Is there any other processing way which makes it faster?

Comment: I think splitting the xml should not be taking much time. Its your processing <!-- stuff --> that takes time to process 10,000 times. So try FORK-JOIN pattern with Collection Splitter and COllection Aggregator. This way the processing <!-- stuff --> will happen in multiple threads and it should take less time to process the whole 10,000 items.

Comment: Sorry for mentioning stuff.
In for-each I am doing nothing but a vm:outbound-endpoint with on-way exchange pattern. So It shouldn't effect the time I guess.

Comment: Are you using EE? If yes, did you look at http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Streaming+Data+Processing+with+DataMapper ?

Comment: I missed it. Will look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*we can achieve this by following few best practices in mule*

1. use sax parser instead of DOM for loading the xml
2. divide the file into chunks and process the chunks parellelly
3. if you are storing the data in several variables do not store the
   complete xml which may cause the memory leak
4. remove variables at the end of each mule flow
          if unnecessary

Comment: "4. remove variables" - Isn't this automatically done? Do you actually have to remove variables manually to avoid memory leaks? I thought that the flow-variables are actually unreferences and freed by the GC when they are not needed anymore.... do you actually have to manually remove them?